# Installing software package developed for AMD64 when my PC has ARM64 architecture

Tags: linux, x86-64, ubuntu-18.04, arm64

I'm somewhat of a linux noob, but I'm trying to use a microcomputer with aarch64 Architecture. I am trying to download software using wget and a Public Cert Key for software developed for x64/AMD64. When I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

I am assuming it is because it was developed for AMD64. From everything I've found, I think I need a cross compiler to translate the binary from AMD to ARM,but nothing I've found has helped me get any closer to actually installing my desired package. Can anyone give me an ELI5 version or point me in the direction of how to educate myself better on system architectures?

Comment: Sometimes the package has its own Apt repo. It may help us to help you if you indicate the package

Comment: You need a source package to cross compile, or an AArch64 binary package.  Or you'll have to run it in an emulator, e.g. under `qemu`.  **You can't make an ARM64 package out of an x86-64 binary package.**

Comment: Peter Cordes - Can i run an amd64.deb package file on an ARM64 based ubuntu (20.10 desktop) on raspberry pi 4 (8GB ram) using emulation with qemu(  AMD64 emulation to ARM64). How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using update command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to upgrade packages lists

```
sudo apt-get search <generic name of package>
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install <package name found in search>
```

The generic name I mean "apache" instead of "apache-php-modlib"